# how to display project folder information on visual studio on main visual studio IDE window title

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have several different version of same project open from different folders. And all title field on Visual studio IDE are the same because the project name is the same. I have to click on the properties to see the folder location. I am wondering if an extension can be added to show file folder on the VS IDE window title bar.

Thanks
Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the [Rename Visual Studio Window Title](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f3f23845-5b1e-4811-882f-60b7181fa6d6) extension that automatically changes the window title of Visual Studio to include a folder tree when two instances of Visual Studio are running with the same window title.